# The weight of a drilled out cylinder

Tags: geometry, physics, volume

Cylinder is $2.71$kg or $2710$g, diameter is $5$cm and $7.5$cm high. The volume is $147.18$cm$^3$ and the density is just the mass divided by the volume, I'm not sure if I need to convert it into grams then calculate it. So I just left it to $2.71$kg / $147.18$cm$^3$.

Anyways, the question is

> If a $15$mm diameter hole is drilled through the centre of this cylinder to a depth of $6$cm from one end, and $6.4$ diameter through the remainder what would be the modified cylinders reduce weight?

This question confuses me and I do not understand it. Please help, there is another question part of this which is

> In $\%$ how much material has been removed by the drilling of the 2 holes?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

The density can be computed but is not really needed. If the original weight is given in kg, your answer should presumably be in kg.

The **old volume** is $(\pi)(5/2)^2(7.5)$  cm$^3$. You may want to calculate this using a calculator, but it will turn out it is not necessary to do so.

Now we calculate the **new volume**, which is the old volume minus the combined volume of the holes. The two holes have volume $(\pi)(1.5/2)^2(6)$ and $(\pi)(0.32)^2(1.5)$ respectively. I have assumed the second hole has diameter $6.4$ mm, the units were not specified. It has depth $1.5$ cm, since the original cylinder has height $7.5$, and the first hole is $6$ cm deep. We had to convert the hole diameters to cm from the given information, which was in mm.

So the new volume is
$$(\pi)(5/2)^2(7.5)- (\pi)(1.5/2)^2(6)-(\pi)(0.32)^2(1.5).$$
Thus the **fraction** of the original material remaining is 
$$\frac{(\pi)(5/2)^2(7.5)- (\pi)(1.5/2)^2(6)-(\pi)(0.32)^2(1.5)}{(\pi)(5/2)^2(7.5)}.\tag{1}$$
Cancel the $\pi$ and calculate. For the weight remaining, multiply (1) by the original weight.

The percentage of material removed can be calculated from the information above.

Comment: I am very confuse with the answer ._.

Comment: It way take a while to absorb. Although it is not necessary, you may want to compute the volumes of the two holes, from the formulas I gave, using a calculator. That may give you a more concrete feeling about what's happening.

Comment: @alexqwx: The original problem as put by the OP uses the term "weight," so I think the answer should also use "weight."

Comment: Got it ${}{}{}{}$.

Comment: I agree that making careful distinction between mass and weight is important, but ordinary usage does not.

Comment: Calculated it and I got 0.92...(What would be the unit)
Im confuse what to do
I did not understand what you meant by
"Cancel the π and calculate. For the weight remaining, multiply (1) by the original weight." <- On which step? (Sorry I am very confuse and this is my first time with these type of questions so I deeply apologise for my lack of intelligence :(

Comment: I checked quickly, and get the ratio (1) is about $0.895232$. But my calculations are not reliable. The weight of the reduced cylinder would then be this times $2.71$, so about $2.426$.  The *ratio* is a ratio of volumes, so it does not have any units.